# Use 1 Child entity for 2 parent entities

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htKIp.png)

Phone numbers is a common entity for both the Student and employee . How to share the phonenumbers as common Child entity to both the Student and Employee.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a one-to-many relationship between `Student` and `PhoneNumbers` and another one-to-many relationship between `Employee` and `PhoneNumbers`. In order to do this you can use the annotations @OneToMany and @JoinColumn. Here's how the code for Employee would look:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="phone_number_id")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    ...

}
```

This is an example for unidirectional association, there is also a bidirectional one. For more detailed explanation of both associations you can check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).